# Background overflowing from div

Tags: html, css

I am designing a page which has the following HTML structure.

```
<div id="event">
    <div id="event-image">
        <div id="event-image-background">               
        </div>
        <img src="image_url_here">
    </div>
     <div id="event-title">
            EVENT 1
     </div>
    <div id="event-details-summary">
       Event Summary Here
    </div>
    <div id="event-description">
    </div>
</div>
```

And I am using the following CSS for the structure.

```
#event{
position: relative;
}
#event-image{
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto;
border: 1px solid #fff;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px -7px #CCC, -5px 10px 10px -7px #CCC;
overflow: hidden;
}
#event-image-background{
 background: url('image_url_here') no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 0.1;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 2;
}
#event-image img{
opacity: 1;
z-index: 3;
border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0);
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the background that I have applied to event-image-background is overflowing into the other divs, namely event-title and others that follow. I am not really good at CSS, and have no clue what's going wrong. Kindly help.

Thanks :)

PS: I dont really want to use the max-height option, as the image that I will be adding via img src will have variable height for each event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to `#event-image-background`.

*Protip, I'd recommend favoring styling on classes (e.g. `.event-image-background` and `<div class="event-image-background">`) rather than ids. See: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/.*

Comment: overflow:hidden doesnt work. And thanks for the tip. Will keep that in mind

Comment: @psyc0der Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the relevant code so I can, well, fiddle with it?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Should have done it earlier. Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/Ndv7U/

Comment: No worries.  So adding `position:relative` to `#event-image` fixes the overflow.  Does that, like, break everything else, or would that resolve it?

Comment: That works perfectly. At least seems so. Thanks a ton :)